# Is there a way to load data to Azure data lake storage gen 2 using logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have load data to azure datalake storage gen2 using logic app.I tried using the connector azure file storage but i couldn't get any filesytem folder in that.Can some one help me on this issue?
Note: without using copy activity.

Comment: What actions did you use or want to use?

Comment: If you want to upload file to azure data lake, the logic  app has the data lake built-in connector which can easily complete this task.

Comment: @George Chen: Thanks for your reply.i used datalake to read the file and want to load the data into Datalake gen2.

Comment: @Farid: Thanks for your reply.i want to load data to datalake gen2 not datalake.Can you please help on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there has no connector for data lake gen2 in logic app. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/37118125-connector-for-azure-data-lake-gen-2.

Here is a workaround which I have tested to work.
1. create a azure data factory service. 
2. create a pipeline to copy files from data lake gen1 to data lake gen2.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2#load-data-into-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2.

3. use data factory connector in logic app to create a pipeline run. 
   [image]

Once run successfully, the related files will be copied to the target folder under data lake gen2.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't ADLS Gen2 just a blob container? Select the Azure Blob Storage connector, then Create Blob task.

Comment: This is the right answer. Although you can't do everything using the Azure Blob Storage connecter, like renaming or deleting a directory, you can create, update and delete individual blobs, list directory contents and process the returned blobs iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

I selected "Azure Blob Storage" as action in logic app and then selected my ADLSGen2 storage account name. it is working fine. Do you guys see any issue ??

Comment: Is it Working fine ? no issues ?